# Why the accuracy of my model is 0.0? and ETA is always 0 as well

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow.js

*Related with
[My accuracy is at 0.0 and I don't know why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58667517/my-accuracy-is-at-0-0-and-i-dont-know-why)*

My model is a classification problem over 1600 classes given a sequence of text. For that, I used the `sparseCategoricalCrossentropy` loss function. This is the code:

```js
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node';
import * as use from '@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder';

import training from './data/data.json';
import original from './data/original.json'

const classes = ["0", ...original.map(o => o.id)]
const batchSize = 128
const epochs = 600
const embeddingDims = 512;

async function* generator() {
  const m = await use.load()
  for (let i = 0; i < training.length; i += 1) {
    const { intent, text } = training[i]
    yield {
      xs: Array.from((await m.embed(text.toLowerCase())).dataSync()),
      ys: [classes.indexOf(intent)]
    }
  }
}

const dataset = tf.data.generator(generator).batch(batchSize)
const model = tf.sequential();

model.add(tf.layers.dense({
  inputShape: [embeddingDims],
  activation: 'relu',
  units: 64,
}));
model.add(tf.layers.dropout({ rate: 0.25 }));

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    inputShape: [64],
    activation: 'relu',
    units: 64,
  }));
}
model.add(tf.layers.dropout({ rate: 0.25 }));

model.add(tf.layers.dense({
  inputShape: [64],
  activation: 'relu',
  units: 64,
}));

model.compile({
  loss: 'sparseCategoricalCrossentropy',
  optimizer: 'adam',
  metrics: [tf.metrics.sparseCategoricalAccuracy],
});

// Training
model.fitDataset(dataset, { epochs })
  .then(history => {
    console.log('Trained!!', history)
    model.save('file://./model')
  });
```

`training.length` is `121600`, about `76` strings for each class.

The loss function looks that is quite small, looks good (at least for me). But the accuracy I don't understand why is 0.00...

[image]

The model performance is a bit slow, each epoch takes about 1h to complete, so testing by changing hyperparameters is a bit tedious.... Let's see if someone can give me a hand seeing something wrong. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [SparseCategoricalAccuracy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/SparseCategoricalAccuracy) if you are using sparseCategoricalCrossentropy but I don't know how your labels are encoded

Comment: I'm using the `universal-sentence-encoder` model https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/1 

ok, I can add the  SparseCategoricalAccuracy metric and see what it does. Thanks!

Comment: I added the metric `metrics: ['accuracy', tf.metrics.sparseCategoricalAccuracy()]`. And I'm getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'rank' of undefined`

Comment: Ok, now it works the sparseCategoricalAccuracy, I changed to `metrics: [tf.metrics.sparseCategoricalAccuracy],`. But is still 0.00 `loss=0.0325 sparseCategoricalAccuracy$1=0.00`

Comment: I updated the code of the answer + results with this

Comment: check your classes and see if this is really what your want

Comment: yes it is. Just I trained with fasttext library, without deeplearning and the result is quite well... I'm wondering whether to opt for another alternative to neural networks for that problem in the end.